# Calculating a field extension with indeterminates

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $F$ be a field and let $x,y,z$ be indeterminates. Consider $L=F(xz,yz,xy)\subseteq K= F(x,y,z)$. I want to show $[K:L]$ is finite and calculate its value.

Can we just say that $\{x,y,z\}$ is a basis for the extension? Is there a more enlightening way to see why this is true?

Comment: Are you sure that $x\in L$?

Comment: @paf Why should $x \in L$? We want $x$ to be in the base of $K$ over $L$, so it suffices that $x \in K$.

Comment: Right, of course...

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$x^2 = xy \cdot xz \cdot (yz)^{-1} \in L$$
Thus $x$ has degree $2$ over $L$. The same for $y$ and $z$.

Now, note that all elements of $L$ are polynomials of the form
$$\frac{\sum_{i,j,k=0}^n a_{ijk} x^iy^jz^k}{\sum_{p,q,r=0}^m b_{pqr} x^py^qz^r} \qquad \qquad \mbox{with  $\ \ \ i+j+k \equiv p+q+r \equiv 0 \pmod{2}$}$$ 
thus $x,y,z \notin L$.

Comment: This doesn't mean that $x\not\in L$.